# Display audio/video stream title and duration of file in Nautilus folder

Tags: gnome, media, metadata, nautilus

Nautilus can be configured to show metadata about a file, such as a thumbnail of the media, the timestamp, the file size, etc., accompanying the file's icon in the folder view.

Nautilus is also capable of querying and displaying, in the `Properties` → `Audio/Video` tab, the stream metadata such as stream title (e.g. “Episode 24: Lorem Ipsum”), duration (e.g. “24 minutes 53 seconds”), etc .

How can I configure Nautilus to display the stream title and duration in the folder view next to each file icon?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-columns
```

Then open nautilus, go to `View -> Visible Columns...` and tick whatever additional metadata you want.

[for stream title & duration, you'd probably need to select `Title` & `Length`]

(worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04)